# Pandas: How to expand a dataframe between dates and add NaNs to new rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This is a simple one but it is stumping me. I have a data frame consisting of day-level observations by individuals. However, not all individuals are observed on the same day. I need to create rows including the days in which individuals are not observed (i.e., count NaN or 0), between the dates where they are present.

The relevant data looks as follows

```
ID  date        StartDate  EndDate    Count    Cov1  Cov2 Cov3
A   05/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   3      1     F    1   
A   06/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   5      1     F    1
A   07/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   2      1     F    1
A   10/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   7      1     F    1
B   05/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   6      0     M    2   
B   07/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   1      0     M    2
C   01/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   3      1     F    1
C   03/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   7      1     F    1
```

However, I need it to look like this:

```
ID  date        StartDate  EndDate    Count    Cov1  Cov2 Cov3
A   05/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   3      1     F    1   
A   06/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   5      1     F    1
A   07/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   2      1     F    1
A   08/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   0      1     F    1
A   09/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   0      1     F    1
A   10/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   7      1     F    1
B   05/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   6      0     M    2   
B   06/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   0      0     M    2   
B   07/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   1      0     M    2
C   01/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   3      1     F    1
C   02/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   0      1     F    1
C   03/05/2005    04/04/05   06/06/2006   7      1     F    1
```

So, the data should expand by days not counted in the original but between the start and end dates. However, the count variable must not copy over, while all other covariates have to copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` by column `date` first, so possible use custom lambda function with [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html), remove first level of MultiIndex and convert index to column `date`, last use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for original format `DD/MM/YYYY`:

First is possible test duplicated rows by columns `ID, date`:

```
print (df[df.duplicated(['ID','date'], keep=False)])
  ID        date StartDate     EndDate  Count  Cov1 Cov2  Cov3
0  A  05/05/2005  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
1  A  05/05/2005  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
```

If possible, remove duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','date'])
```

---

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

df1 = (df.set_index('date').groupby('ID')
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('D', method='ffill'))
        .droplevel(0)
        .reset_index())

print (df1)
         date ID StartDate     EndDate  Count  Cov1 Cov2  Cov3
0  2005-05-05  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
1  2005-05-06  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      5     1    F     1
2  2005-05-07  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      2     1    F     1
3  2005-05-08  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      2     1    F     1
4  2005-05-09  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      2     1    F     1
5  2005-05-10  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      7     1    F     1
6  2005-05-05  B  04/04/05  06/06/2006      6     0    M     2
7  2005-05-06  B  04/04/05  06/06/2006      6     0    M     2
8  2005-05-07  B  04/04/05  06/06/2006      1     0    M     2
9  2005-05-01  C  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
10 2005-05-02  C  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
11 2005-05-03  C  04/04/05  06/06/2006      7     1    F     1

print (df1.index.name)
None
```

If possible in real data it is `ID` use:

```
df1 = df1.rename_axis(None)
```

---

```
m = df1.merge(df, indicator=True, how='left')['_merge'].eq('left_only')
df1.loc[m, 'Count'] = 0

df1['date'] = df1['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print (df1)
          date ID StartDate     EndDate  Count  Cov1 Cov2  Cov3
0   05/05/2005  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
1   06/05/2005  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      5     1    F     1
2   07/05/2005  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      2     1    F     1
3   08/05/2005  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      0     1    F     1
4   09/05/2005  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      0     1    F     1
5   10/05/2005  A  04/04/05  06/06/2006      7     1    F     1
6   05/05/2005  B  04/04/05  06/06/2006      6     0    M     2
7   06/05/2005  B  04/04/05  06/06/2006      0     0    M     2
8   07/05/2005  B  04/04/05  06/06/2006      1     0    M     2
9   01/05/2005  C  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
10  02/05/2005  C  04/04/05  06/06/2006      0     1    F     1
11  03/05/2005  C  04/04/05  06/06/2006      7     1    F     1
```

Comment: Count should be filled with zero, according to the OP's post

Comment: @sammywemmy - oops.

Comment: Two problems:  I get a 'cannot reindex a non-unique index' error, and I still require the Count variable to be 0 where the rows expand.

Comment: @nj95 - `I get a 'cannot reindex a non-unique index' error` there are duplicates in data, how handle it?

Comment: for duplicates, instead of reindex, you might have to build the dates separately, and do an outer join

Comment: @nj95 - `Count` is set to `0

Comment: @nj95 - added solution for remove duplicates for avoid `cannot reindex a non-unique index' error`

Comment: So, this gets the closest. However, I am having a problem during the merge with another value error: "date Is both an index level and a column label which is ambiguous."

Comment: @nj95 - Just tested `print (df1.index.name)`, also `print (df.index.name)` are both `None`, for you not?

Comment: Ok, I fixed that. Now, when I run the df1.loc it's just returning 0s and NaNs

Comment: @nj95 - is used `df1['date'] = df1['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` after `merge` ?

Comment: @nj95 - DataFrames `df1` and `df` are same names in your code?

Comment: Yeah, I ran that as well. Only difference is the dataframes are 'test' and 'test1'

Comment: @nj95 - Is same `print (df1.date.dtype)` and `print (df.date.dtype)` ?

Comment: @nj95 - If yes, try change `m = df1.merge(df, indicator=True, how='left')['_merge'].eq('left_only')` to `m = df1.merge(df, indicator=True, how='left', on=['ID','date'])['_merge'].eq('left_only')`

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which abstracts the process of exposing missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df = pd.read_clipboard() # ignore this, just me reading in the data

# converting the date to date time, 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
# create an anonymous function to generate all dates 
# between the max and min date for each combination 
# of ID, start date and end date
new_dates = {'date':lambda d: pd.date_range(d.min(), d.max(), freq='D')}

(df
.complete(new_dates, 
          by = ['ID','StartDate','EndDate'], 
          fill_value = {'Count':0})
.ffill(downcast='infer')
)
   ID       date StartDate     EndDate  Count  Cov1 Cov2  Cov3
0   A 2005-05-05  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
1   A 2005-05-06  04/04/05  06/06/2006      5     1    F     1
2   A 2005-05-07  04/04/05  06/06/2006      2     1    F     1
3   A 2005-05-08  04/04/05  06/06/2006      0     1    F     1
4   A 2005-05-09  04/04/05  06/06/2006      0     1    F     1
5   A 2005-05-10  04/04/05  06/06/2006      7     1    F     1
6   B 2005-05-05  04/04/05  06/06/2006      6     0    M     2
7   B 2005-05-06  04/04/05  06/06/2006      0     0    M     2
8   B 2005-05-07  04/04/05  06/06/2006      1     0    M     2
9   C 2005-05-01  04/04/05  06/06/2006      3     1    F     1
10  C 2005-05-02  04/04/05  06/06/2006      0     1    F     1
11  C 2005-05-03  04/04/05  06/06/2006      7     1    F     1
```